# ack is not doing a recursive grep

Tags: grep, ack

`ack` (the `grep` tool written in Perl) does not find a file that `grep -r` finds, and I cannot find the right options to get it to work. The following shows `ack` did not find the target string, which is in a regular file in a sub-directory.  It's on Bash shell (Ubuntu 11.04):

```
100 $ grep -r imbue *
    hel/find:              the  fact that some shells including Bash imbue braces
    ## Note: grep find it as shown in the above.

101 $ ./ack-standalone   imbue  
    ## Note: ack didn't find it as shown in the above.

102 $ ./ack-standalone   --version
    ack 1.96
    Running under Perl 5.10.1 at /usr/bin/perl

    Copyright 2005-2011 Andy Lester.

    This program is free software.  You may modify or distribute it
    under the terms of the Artistic License v2.0.

    ## This is the testing folder structure:
103 $ tree
    .
        ack-standalone
        hel
          |-  dot
          |-  find
          |-  grep
          |-  jobs
        perlman
        perlre
        perlrequick
        perlrun
        perlvar
        xargs

    1 directory, 11 files
```

Version 2 of ack, from apt-get package installation, got same results.  In the stand-alone version (version 1) shown above. `ack -f` shows nothing, and I tried the `-r` and `*` options, all with the same results.

On another machine, Ubuntu 10.04, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me if I select to operate in all files regardless of its type, using `-a` switch (my version is same that yours):

```
ack -a imbue *
```

Comment: Ack 1.x only searches files of types it understands. Basically, ack only searches source code in files that it recognizes as source code based on the extension. It is NOT a general purpose grep replacement.  Also, in the `ack -a imbue *` example there, the `*` should not be included.  You never want to specify a filename to ack unless you have a reason to specify a filename to ack.

Comment: 'It is not a general purpose grep replacement.' The first line of `ack` man page states: "Ack is designed as a replacement for 99% of the uses of grep."